# EWS : Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

```
    var message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchangeService, itemid,
                                       new PropertySet(
                                                       ItemSchema.Attachments));




    exchangeService.TraceListener=new TraceListener();
    exchangeService.TraceEnabled = true;
    message.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent)); // Getting exception here.
   //  File.WriteAllBytes("email.eml", message.MimeContent.Content);
```

I am getting the below exception when trying to load the mime content.

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException occurred
>   HResult=-2146233088   Message=The request failed. Unable to read data
>   from the transport connection: The connection was closed.
>   Source=Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(IEwsHttpWebResponse
>   response)
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.InternalExecute()
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalLoadPropertiesForItems(IEnumerable`1
>   items, PropertySet propertySet, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalLoad(PropertySet
>   propertySet)
>          at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObject.Load(PropertySet
>   propertySet)
>          at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in f:\Projects\EmailArchiving\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line
>   34   InnerException: System.IO.IOException
>          HResult=-2146232800
>          Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.
>          Source=System
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>               at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>               at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>               at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
>               at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
>               at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
>               at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
>               at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
>               at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
>               at System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read()
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsXmlReader.Read()
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexProperty.InternalLoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader
>   reader, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String xmlElementName, Func`2
>   readAction)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexProperty.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader
>   reader, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String xmlElementName)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexProperty.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader
>   reader, String xmlElementName)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexPropertyDefinitionBase.InternalLoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader
>   reader, PropertyBag propertyBag)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexPropertyDefinitionBase.LoadPropertyValueFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader
>   reader, PropertyBag propertyBag)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertyBag.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader
>   reader, Boolean clear, PropertySet requestedPropertySet, Boolean
>   onlySummaryPropertiesRequested)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObject.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader
>   reader, Boolean clearPropertyBag, PropertySet requestedPropertySet,
>   Boolean summaryPropertiesOnly)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsServiceXmlReader.ReadServiceObjectsCollectionFromXml[TServiceObject](XmlNamespace
>   collectionXmlNamespace, String collectionXmlElementName,
>   GetObjectInstanceDelegate`1 getObjectInstanceDelegate, Boolean
>   clearPropertyBag, PropertySet requestedPropertySet, Boolean
>   summaryPropertiesOnly)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsServiceXmlReader.ReadServiceObjectsCollectionFromXml[TServiceObject](String
>   collectionXmlElementName, GetObjectInstanceDelegate`1
>   getObjectInstanceDelegate, Boolean clearPropertyBag, PropertySet
>   requestedPropertySet, Boolean summaryPropertiesOnly)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.GetItemResponse.ReadElementsFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader
>   reader)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader
>   reader, String xmlElementName)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.ParseResponse(EwsServiceXmlReader
>   reader)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(EwsServiceXmlReader
>   ewsXmlReader)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponseXml(Stream
>   responseStream)
>               at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(IEwsHttpWebResponse
>   response)
>          InnerException:

What can be the reasons for this exception?

Comment: can you attach http request/response dump?

Comment: I later figured out that this was because of [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196614/the-item-you-tried-to-access-to-longer-exists)