# The item you tried to access to longer exists

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010, outlook-web-app

Here is the screen-shot of an email whose attachment I am trying to access.

[image]

When I try to open the attachment, I am getting the below error

[image]

What is the reason behind this, and how can this be solved?

I am trying to process emails using EWS api and my process is stuck on this email because while processing this email I am getting  the below error(when Loading the MimeContent of this particular email).

this is the code

```
var message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchangeService, itemid,
                                       new PropertySet(
                                                       ItemSchema.Attachments));

    exchangeService.TraceListener=new TraceListener();
    exchangeService.TraceEnabled = true;
    message.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent)); // Getting exception here.
   //  File.WriteAllBytes("email.eml", message.MimeContent.Content);
```

And this is the error I am getting.

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException occurred
>   HResult=-2146233088   Message=The request failed. Unable to read data
>   from the transport connection: The connection was closed.
>   Source=Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your code that is processing the emails so we can see where the problem may be coming from.

Comment: Bob, Added code. Also here is another [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193436/ews-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-the-connection-was-clos) that I posted for the error I am getting.

Comment: It looks like at least part of the problem is that you are loading the email message when you really want to load the attachment of the message. Is this the same client server where you were having problems accessing an attached contact? You mentioned in another post that it was working on your server but not theirs (2010 with no service packs installed).

Comment: The problem here is when I try to get the Mime content of an email which has attachment that gives me the above error when i try to open it(attachment) in OWA, gives the error. Any reason why it shows the error message "the item you tried to access no longer exist" when trying to open the attachment in OWA? I believe if i this error is fixed, I can be able to get the mime content of the email. Yes it's the same client but the error is different this time.